# How to convert 3 image view coordinate lists(i.e 3 2d lists) into a single 3-d list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I hope my question is phrased correctly. So I have a 3d-image that I have viewed on 3 different axes (top,side and front views) and I have obtained the coordinates that this ROI is present on all 3 planes (x-y,y-z,z-x). The problem is when marking the ROIs, one plane could have points that when projected would not at all lie on another plane. I'm trying to run a loop that would allow me to create an x,y,z list that would essentially contain the intersection of these 3 axes.
This is the algorithm I have thought of:

```
3d_image_projection = np.array(size(image), type=uint8))
For x in range(0,xaxis):
  for y in range(0,yaxis):
  if (!xy(x,y)):
     continue
     for z in range (0,zaxis):
         if (!zx(z,x)):
            continue
         if (!yz(y,z)):
            continue
            # If here, this x,y,z is inside the intersection. Assign 1 to this pixel.
         3d_image_projection[x][y][z] = 1
# Crop the mask to only allow pixels that have 1
```

Since these are numpy arrays, I am not able to write (!xy(x,y)) to check if this lies inside the (x,y) coordinate list. (Similarily for the other 2 axes)

How do I solve this?

Update:
I think I've got the code to run like this:

```
#The dimensions of my 3d image
mask_full = np.zeros((610,410,422),dtype=np.uint8)
a= [ list(item) for item in zx ]
b = [ list(item) for item in xy ]
c = [ list(item) for item in yz ]
for x in range(610):
    for y in range(410):
        if ([x,y] not in b):
            continue
        for z in range(422):
            if([z,x] not in a):
                continue
            if ([y,z] not in c):
                continue
            #count+=1
            mask_full[x][y][z] = 1
```

However, as you can see, I end up with 100 million + iterations which takes forever. Is there a much, much faster way for me to do this?

Update 3:
Here are the images
[Z-X Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EdHB.png)
[X-Y Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sKlD.png)[Y-Z Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v95Hk.png)
.I have the coordinates of the ROIs marked in yellow, blue and red [Which are 3 2d numpy arrays i.e. zx,xy,yz in the code snippet above]. I'm trying to combine these 3 to create a single 3d array which contains the intersection of these 3 arrays. My image is a 610x410x422 image. I hope this makes my question clearer.

Comment: In the algorithm you shared `xy`, `yz`, and `zx` are not defined. What is the value of these variables?

Comment: xy contains the coordinates where the ROI is present on the xy plane, yz contains coordinate pixels on the yz plane and zx on the zx plane. I'm sorry did you want actual values?

Comment: @VigneshKrishnan yes, otherwise this can't be debugged. Also please give smaller picture examples.

Comment: You need a variation of [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [advanced indexing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_advanced_indexing.htm). Can't solve this without sample data input and output, as even the dimensions are not clear to me.

Comment: Does this make it clearer?